# bash: writing to the file descriptor #3 of an unnamed (anonymous) pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, file-descriptors

I need to call a PHP interpreter, which is in a docker container, from my Linux host system. For some reasons I don't want to install PHP on the host system. Now I'm trying to call PHP in this way:

```bsh
cat script.php | docker exec -i php_container_name php -- --param1=value1
```

I also need to pass some binary data to the standard input of this PHP script. But this channel is busy (because the PHP source code is passed through the standard input).
I've tried to do such things as:

1. Use a named pipe like this:

```bsh
cat script.php | docker exec -i php_container_name php -- --param1=value1 pipe-name="/path/to/the/file"
```

And to read on the PHP side the content of this pipe. But by doing this I've to share the pipe file between the container and the system, and that's an extra operation I'd rather avoid.

2. Use an unnamed pipe #3 like this:

```bsh
exec 3> >(docker exec -i php_container_name php -- --param1=value1)
cat ./script.php >&3
```

So in the last line I need to pass data to the file descriptor #3 of an unnamed pipe. Something like this:

```bsh
cat ./script.php >&3 3<`echo -e "line1\nline2"`
```

But this does not work. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I don’t know much about Docker, but (1) You say “I also need to pass some binary data *to **the standard input*** of this PHP script.” (emphasis added).  But then you go on to indicate that you may be able to pass the data in through a pipe whose name is on the command line — so it doesn’t have to be standard input, does it?  I guess you mean “I need to *pass some binary data* to this PHP script.”  By getting overly specific, you confuse the situation.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) It seems to me (and remember, I admit that I’m not an expert in this) that the simplest solution would be to copy the PHP code to a file in the container, and then run the interpreter on that local (container-resident) file, taking (data) input from the pipe. (3) You talk about using a named pipe, and “sharing the pipe file between the container and the [host] system”. But couldn’t you use a named pipe ***in the container**?* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (0) It seems to me that your problem is “how do I run a command in a Docker container with two simultaneous (but separate) streams of data coming from outside the container?” By titling your question something completely different (and tagging it according to *your **attempted solution*** rather than the question), you fall into the trap of the [“XY Problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and risk repelling the people who will be best able to answer your actual question.